# what is courgette.log file and why was it automatically saved on my desktop?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-desktop, windows-11, courgette

I looked up on the internet and it said `courgette.log` file is based on **docker**.
I am using `Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701` on `Windows 11 Home.`

But I have ***docker*** installed for a long time now. Why did `courgette.log` file appear today itself `empty` and with `size: 0 bytes.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known issue related to GitHub:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12468

`courgette.log` is created each time you're going to update `Docker desktop`.

Issue are reproduced on `Windows 11` and `Windows 10`.

This log file is apparently created by an executable file called `courgette64.exe` into Docker installation folder.

Do not hesitate to remove it, it does not cause any side effects.

Chromium projects related links:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/courgette/+/HEAD
https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette/